# iCloud low speed to retrieve data

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, magicalrecord

I use Core Date and iCloud in my app, but the speed for retrieving data is too low. To create the Core Data stack, I've used MagicalRecords method

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithiCloudContainer:nil localStoreNamed:@"base"];
```

Can I retrieve data not in the main thread? The loading takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use GCD.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithiCloudContainer:nil 
                                         localStoreNamed:@"base"];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          // update your UI if necessary
    });
});
```